# Testing Android Apps with Implicit Broadcasts and Background Services Unavailable

Tags: android, adb, broadcast

The Android Developers website suggests that we try out running our applications without implicit broadcasts and background services. For this, they've mentioned the following command [here](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/background-optimization.html)

```
adb shell cmd appops set RUN_IN_BACKGROUND ignore
```

However, when I try running it on my machine, I get the following error -

```
Error: Unknown operation string: ignore
```

Has anyone been able to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this one by looking at the source code of AppOpsCommand.

You need to give the package name of the app, and it will work -

```
adb shell cmd appops set <PACKAGE> RUN_IN_BACKGROUND ignore
```